# Similar Array items but not exact ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I would like to see if I can check 2 arrays with similar values against each other and return the items that are different between the 2. However I have items that have similar names and I would want those to be excluded as well.
Example:

```
pantry = ["apples", "chedder cheese mild", "flour", "salt"] 
recipe = ["bacon", "chedder cheese sharp", "flour", "chocolate"]
#=> desired return ["apples","bacon", "chocolate", "salt"]
```

What I get using `pantry - recipe #=> ["apples", "bacon", "chocolate", "salt", "cheddar cheese mild"]`

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Basically you're asking for magic, where by magic I mean something that can't be achieved without significant amount of work (like using ElasticSearch).

Comment: What's the logic behind removing `"chedder cheese sharp"` and `"chedder cheese mild"` from desired return value?

Comment: And what's the logic behind having `"apples"` before `"bacon"` but `"salt"` after `"chocolate"`? Does the order in `pantry` and `recipe` matter or not? Are they always the same size?

Comment: You need to define programmatically what "similar" means and then this will be fairly easy.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that "similar" means multi word strings where all but the last word are the same...

```
pantry = ["apples", "chedder cheese mild", "flour", "salt"]
recipe = ["bacon", "chedder cheese sharp", "flour", "chocolate"]

result = (pantry + recipe).group_by{|x| x.slice(0,(x.index(/[\s][^\s]+\z/) || x.size))}
result = result.values.select{|x|x.size == 1}.flatten.sort
=> ["apples", "bacon", "chocolate", "salt"]
```